Why can Total Least Squares Regression not have a solution?
I was looking at this reference on TLS regression. I understand the math which says that there can be problems where no solution exists. Based on my understanding, the minimum perturbation to the $C$ matrix to make it rank $N$, the resulting null-space might not have a non-zero last coordinate. My question is, in such a case, reduce the rank of $C$ to $N-1$ and see if there is a vector in the null-space with non-zero last element. If not, make its rank $N-2$ and so on.
Geometrically, I can not see why it is possible to not have a solution!
Edit: Please consider non-degenrate examples where feature matrix $A$ of size $n \times m$ ($n$ data points, $m$ dimensional features including $1$s) is of rank $m$ and output $y$ is not collinear with the features so $[A\ y]$ is of rank $m+1$.

I imagine that no-solution to the least-squares problem generally implies that several solutions are equally minimal; none is "least". This might happen when trying to fit a line thru data with only one x-value, or trying to fit the sum of two lines to data.

@Angelica I have seen references that specifically distinguish no solution and unique solution. For uniqueness, we need the lowest singular value to be strictly less than the other singular values.
